# For Pentecostals who have experienced the gift of prophecy. Is the gift of prophecy the same as interpretation of tongues?

Tags: spiritual-gifts

If tongues is a supernatural utterance given by the Holy Spirit in an unknown tongue, and interpretation of tongues is an utterance given by the Holy Spirit in a known language, then is prophecy, which likewise is an utterance given by the Holy Spirit in a known language, the same as interpretation of tongues?

Please narrow responses to the gift of prophecy and not the office of a prophet.

As a side note, in Acts 2, on the day of Pentecost, when the Holy Spirit spoke through the disciples through that utterance, that seems to be the gift of prophecy, not unknown tongues since those hearing the disciples understood them in their native languages.

Comment: There are too many views about spiritual gifts, you really need to specify whose perspective you want.